# Knockout: binding to an ID which contains a period?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dropdown that looks something like the following:

```html
<select id="Object1.PropertyX" name="Object1.PropertyX" data-bind="value: Object1.PropertyX">
//etc
</select>
```

It gets this ID from ASP.NET MVC where it's a property on an object.

Bindings are applied via `ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $("body")[0]);`.

Upon page load, the following error occurs:

```
knockout-3.4.2.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return (($root.ComparingProperty() !='') && ($root.Object1.PropertyX() != $root.ComparingProperty())) }"
Message: Cannot read property 'PropertyX' of undefined
```

`$root` is equivalent to `ko.dataFor(document.body)`.

After this, `$root` in the console shows that `Object1.PropertyX` does in fact exist there and `Symbol(_latestValue)` has the value of the property at page load. However, `$root.Object1` is undefined and `Symbol(_latestValue)` does not change with the dropdown.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Knockout uses the dot-notation to navigate through objects. `data-bind="value: Object1.PropertyX"` means binding `PropertyX` of object `Object1`, which throws the `$root.Object1 is undefined` error because `Object1` doesn't exist.

You can use the `$data` [binding context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) to reference the property of the currently bound object by bracket notation: `data-bind="value: $data['Object1.PropertyX']"`. Have a look at the following example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  'Object1.PropertyX': ko.observable()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select id="Object1.PropertyX" name="Object1.PropertyX" data-bind="value: $data['Object1.PropertyX']">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<p>
  Object1.PropertyX: <strong data-bind="text: $data['Object1.PropertyX']"></strong>
</p>
```